# Why is a document reference variable slower than document object itself?

Tags: javascript

Since it's said that the closer the variable is to the function running, the better it will perform, I assumed that setting `let doc = document` (and also `let win = window`) would perform better or at least the same compared to using the document (or window) object itself (eg. `document.getElementById('id')` vs `doc.getElementById('id')`). And since the name itself can be made shorter, it's pleasant having the shorter references.

However in my testing the reference was 1.5 times slower than the original object. Is there any reason behind this? Does the "closer scope rule" not apply to these frequently used basic objects because browsers assume that they will be used a lot?

Quick benchmark:

```
let doc, f1, f2;

doc = document;

f1 = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) document.body;
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) document.head;
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) document.getElementsByTagName('body');
};

f2 = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) doc.body;
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) doc.head;
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) doc.getElementsByTagName('body');
};

for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    console.time(1);
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) f1();
    console.timeEnd(1);

    console.time(2);
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) f2();
    console.timeEnd(2);
}

/*
Results:
1: 1162ms
2: 1687ms
1: 1096ms
2: 1648ms
1: 1079ms
2: 1644ms
*/
```

Comment: Show your benchmarking setup. More than likely the timing wasn't done correctly.

Comment: I think you're forgetting about the cost of declaring the extra variable.

Comment: 1) Your entire question is based on incorrect information. The distance (in lines of code) between a variable and a function that uses it has absolutely nothing to do with performance. Well, except that in some scenarios it keeps the variable long in the memory and only when memory goes low then it affects the performance, but in that case the code has greater issues to deal with. 2) How your examples make the variables closer? Where are the functions? 3) There is a cost for declaring new variables, although negligible. 4) None of that accounts to 1.5 times, so incorrect benchmarks.

Comment: @RacilHilan: OP is probably referring to "distance" in the prototype chain.

Comment: Added quick benchmark benchmark to main post.

Comment: @Cerbrus Hmm, yes I considered that, but then the entire question's wording is incorrect. That's the levels of object's members, and regardless whether they're functions or values. So the question becomes *the fewer levels of object's members the better*, which is now correct, except it still shouldn't account to 1.5 times, should it?

Comment: @Racil Hilan & Cerbrus Yes the "prototype chain distance" was what I meant. Sorry for poor wording, English isn't my native language and I'm just hobby coder, so the terminology is sometimes lost on me.

Comment: OK, no worries about the language. At least now you learnt something new :-). Welcome to SO.

Answer (score -1):

FWIW, in Chrome, a local clearly wins over global, and a non-local is even faster:

```js
LOOPS = 100000

function test(loops, fn, arg) {
  var t = new Date;
  while (loops--) fn(arg);
  console.log((new Date) - t);
}

function global() {
    test(LOOPS, () => window.outerHeight);
}

function local() {
    var win = window;
    test(LOOPS, () => win.outerHeight);
}

var win2 = window;

function nonlocal() {
    test(LOOPS, () => win2.outerHeight);
}

function arg() {
    var win3 = window;
    test(LOOPS, (x) => x.outerHeight, win3);
}


global()
local()
nonlocal()
arg()
```

Comment: All 3 tests are ~20-22 for me. Google Chrome on Win 10. I'd suggest multiplying the iteration (at least) tenfold. Get some more significant numbers.

Comment: Interesting, here I also get localWin as the faster function (though I didn't get such a big difference - avg. 30 for global, 27 for local).

Comment: What you called *non-local* is actually also global. Also your results don't really make sense, similar to the OP's 1.5 times. As @Cerbrus mentioned, the results should be much closer. I've tested it in 3 browsers and got very close results.

Comment: To interpret the results. Firstly, I don't think this is a good example of fewer levels of members as it is actually using the exact same levels (one level). The difference between using `window` and a variable can be due to browser's engine JS optimization (similar to compressing JS where it compresses variable names but not `window`). The shouldn't be any measurable difference between local and global (*non-local* as you called it) variables in your particular test because both are outside the function and still in scope when printing the results.